# If Statement Syntax in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I get an error with the below code on the line that says, `if (str(listGroup) == "FTPDST"):`. I'm pretty sure my if, elif, else statement is correct syntax. Please let me know if my syntax is wrong on that line or anywhere else I get errors because the below code won't run, and it throws an `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for the line, `if (str(listGroup) == "FTPDST")`. My list have been initialized in my code. I'm just not showing it below. Thanks.

```
def parseConfigForIso(searchString, listGroup):
    fi = open(panConfig,"r") 
    for line in fi:
        if searchString in line: 
            lineList=line.split() 
            for item in listList:
                m = re.search(r'(\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}(-\d{2}|slash\d{2})?',item, re.M|re.I)  
                if m:
                    if (str(listGroup) == "FTPDST"): 
                        ftpDstList.append(str(m.group(0))
                    elif (str(listGroup) == "FTPSRC"):
                        ftpSrcList.append(str(m.group(0)) 
                    elif (str(listGroup) == "SSHDST"):
                        sshDstList.append(str(m.group(0))
                    elif (str(listGroup) == "APPID"):
                        appIdList.append(str(m.group(0))
                    else:
                        print "you inputted an incorrect group as a parameter into the parseConfigForIso function"
    fi.close()
parseConfigForIso('search string', "FTPSRC")
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace. It may point to the problem.

Comment: All `.append`ing lines have unbalanced parenthesis. Three are opened, two are closed.

Comment: the line above is missing a paren: `ftpDstList.append(str(m.group(0))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a `)` in all `.append(str(m.group(0))`.